# Add input field attribute after certain number of button clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently trying to add an attribute to an input field when a certain number of clicks occur,`2`. I added a variable called `add_count` that iterates `+ 1` everytime the button is clicked. But when running the jquery function. It is not executing at all. How can I add an attribute to the input field once the click is greater than `2`?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
var click_count = 0;
    $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
    console.log(click_count++);
        if (add_count => 2){
        newSection.children(':first').children(':first').attr('id', 'person_id_' + newNum).attr('name', 'person_id_' + newNum).attr('class', 'newIncrement');
        }
        newSection.children(':first').children(':first').attr('id', 'person_id_' + newNum).attr('name', 'person_id_' + newNum);
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: What is `newNum` and `click_count` ? Dont see you incrementing `add_count`. Also note that you can pass in an object to attr. i.e `.attr({'id': 'person_id_' + newNum,name = name }).addClass('newIncrement')`

Comment: ^^_ `.attr({'id': 'person_id_' + newNum,'name' : name }).addClass('newIncrement')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've messed up your operator, change

```
if (add_count => 2){...
```

to

```
if (add_count >= 2){...
```

and note that `add_count` is not the same as `click_count`